# stored procedure isn't working with EF 4.0 and WCF Data Services

Tags: stored-procedures, wcf-data-services

I'm working with EF4 and WCF Data Services. I'd like to take my current SQL connection and rewire it using this method so that I can access the data from a variety of clients (mobile, web, Win Client).  I know I can use LINQ but I was just wondering about using stored procs instead.

Here is my sample stored proc:

```
CREATE procedure getuserbyID (
@UserID int)
AS 
SELECT Firstname, Lastname, Email From TestDatabase WHERE UserID = @UserID
```

In my `TestDataService.svc`, I have the following in `InitialService`:

```
config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Users", EntitySetRights.All);
config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("GetUserByID", ServiceOperationRights.All
```

I also call the stored proc in the file as listed here:

```
[WebGet]
public List<User> GetUserByID(string UserID)
{
   TestEntities entity = new TestEntities();
   return entity.GetUserByID(Convert.ToInt32(UserID)).ToList();
}
```

In my EF model, I have imported the stored proc as a function and saved it as `GetUserByID` and it returns a `User` entity.

When I test it, I am able to access the entities by viewing it in the browser using:
`http://localhost:1753/TestWcfDataService.svc` or `http://localhost:1753/TestWcfDataService.svc/Users` or `http://localhost:1753/TestWcfDataService.svc/Users(1)` -- sample user with a `UserID` of 1

I know it's working with LINQ and ODATA via the Service but when I try to access the stored procedure via this:

`http://localhost:1753/TestWcfDataService.svc/GetUserByID?UserID='1'` -- then I get an HTTP 500 Error that the page cannot be displayed.  I debug it and I view the error and here it is:

> System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException
>   was unhandled by user code Message=The
>   data reader is incompatible with the
>   specified 'TestModel.User'. A member
>   of the type, 'UserID', does not have a
>   corresponding column in the data
>   reader with the same name.

`UserID` is my primary key and identity in the `Users` table. Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Just a guess, but your stored procedure returns columns which look like the User entity, but they do not contain the key property UserID. I think EF needs the key property value in order to materialize the entity. Did you try returning the UserID as one of the columns from the stored proc?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error and sorry for wasting your time.  A mishap on my part.  Because the UserID is my primary key I wasn't using it in my select criteria thus there was no column in the data reader.  So, to recap: Ensure all your filter criteria are also listed in the select criteria in your stored procedure.  Simply changing my stored proc to (below) corrected it.

```
CREATE procedure getuserbyID
(@UserID int)
AS
SELECT UserID, Firstname, Lastname, Email From TestDatabase WHERE UserID = @UserID
```